# Use plupload on iOS with chunking. Even if I upload the same image, it always gets a GUID for the file name I want the original file name

Tags: ios, plupload

Is the any way to get the original file name so that when I upload the same image I can have the option to replace it on the server?

I have unique_names set to false, but that does not work.

Comment: Perhaps showing what you have tried would help.

Comment: In the function:

handlePluploadFilesAdded( uploader, files )

I have tried dumping the files object to see if there is anything unique in there, there's not. The time stamp is the current system time stamp not the time the image was modified. The file name is a random GUID and changes for the same image every time you add the image to the queue.